# 社会主義体制下のソ連時代。Clarification on this sentence

Tags: grammar, translation

社会主義体制下のソ連時代。

This sentence is structured in a way that is very confusing to me. The best way I can translate this is 'The Soviet era under the Socialist System'

Any better ways to translate this.

Comment: What's wrong with your translation? Doesn't fit to the context? I'm afraid we don't know the context.

Comment: Note that it's actually a noun phrase rather than a sentence.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused because it parses like a noun phrase, but the 「。」 at the end denotes that it is a complete sentence. This is actually a valid way of writing and is called [体言止め](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/what-exactly-is-%E4%BD%93%E8%A8%80%E6%AD%A2%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%92%E3%82%93%E3%81%A9%E3%82%81 "what exactly is “体言止め”?").

Answer (score 1):

'The Soviet era under the Socialist System'で問題ないと思います。
なお、新聞や雑誌などの記事で、冒頭部分が「社会主義体制下のソ連時代。」のように体言止めでブツ切りにされていて、その次に別の文が続く表現はマスメディアの表現方法として頻繁に見られます。