# Grammatically, is a 体言止めの文 a "Japanese sentence"?

Tags: terminology

In Japanese, a **文【ぶん】** is basically anything which is delimited by periods (マル) or question/exclamation marks. For example, let's say there is a paragraph like this in the middle of the main text of a novel.

> 夕暮れの川岸を一人で歩く俺。太陽の光を浴びて輝く水面。頬を撫でる風。

Here, we have rather simple [体言止め](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/5010) expressions, which make this paragraph compact yet dramatic. Despite being 体言止め, I believe there are **three 文** in this paragraph, simply because there are three periods. If I were to explain this paragraph with grammatical terms, I would say something like this: "This is a paragraph which contains three sentences. Each sentence lacks a main predicate; instead, one long noun phrase forms the entire sentence."

However, on this site, I keep seeing assertions like "Strictly/Grammatically speaking, this is not a sentence in the first place" to explain this pattern. And to my surprise, apparently many users favor this type of explanation. The most recent example is [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48811/5010).

So I thought, "Ah okay, **grammatically** speaking, *sentence* in English means something different from 文 in Japanese, and a *sentence* always needs a main predicate!"

However, I failed to find any credible source to support this. All the serious English articles I've read so far say that a sentence doesn't necessarily have a main predicate. For example, "Hi.", "Yes.", "At three o'clock." and "Two pizzas with cheese crust, please." are English sentences (categorized as [minor sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(linguistics)#Major_and_minor_sentences)) simply because they begin with a capital letter and end with a period. Simply put, I found essentially no difference between *sentence* in English and 文 in Japanese.

So my question is as follows: Is 文 different from *sentence*? Ordinary English speakers have an idea of *sentence* which is different from the formal dictionary definition? English speakers who are learning Japanese actually tend to feel **there is no sentence** in the paragraph above? If yes, how many sentences are there in [this article](http://ja.uncyclopedia.info/wiki/%E4%BD%93%E8%A8%80%E6%AD%A2%E3%82%81)? I feel there are dozens of 文's, and I have never doubted that. On a website where not everyone is an expert, is it unsafe/misleading/unpractical to call the 文 above 'Japanese sentences'?

As far as I can tell, I have never seen a Japanese article which says something like "体言止めの"文"には述語がないので、厳密な文法的には文ではありません".

Comment: One thing I wonder about this question is whether the word "sentence" used by linguistics has strayed some distance from the word "sentence" used by (a) grammarians [as in ordinary "English" language instructors = 国語] and (b) the recipients of a standard education. As a native speaker of English but in category (b), I'd be hesitant to call "Hello" a sentence and expect that this usage would raise some quizzical looks.

Comment: @virmaior And as a recipient of a standard Japanese education, I never hesitated to call "こんにちは。" a 文. So that's exactly the point of this question. If what you're saying is the general fact among English speakers, I'll have to respect that on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I went to school (K12 in the US during the 70's and early 80's), I was taught that a sentence had to have a subject and a predicate (usually they said *verb* instead of *predicate*).  But then what exactly are things like "Hello!"

Broadly speaking, what I was taught works very well for formally written, academic, and business English.  But often when I write in my journal or even when writing comments on students papers, the style I write in is a rather abbreviated form omitting subjects or occasionally verbs.  Yet, what I write is still punctuated, and for want of a better word, I would most likely call them sentences despite the fact that they don't line up with what I was taught.

I think for me what I would call a sentence is something that is recognizable as a complete thought.  So in grading a paper, I might write in the margin "poor word choice".  I think that expresses a whole thought but I wouldn't be surprised that some would be pedantic enough to argue it's not a proper sentence.

Today I dropped by my local 紀伊国屋 and picked up a copy of マララ.  First I was struck by how different it reads in Japanese from English.  It made me wonder what the original text was written in.  But more to the point, I noticed that many of the *sentences* in the Japanese translation just weren't really what I would have thought of as sentences.  They just seemed to end with out a verb.  Sometimes they just ended at what felt like mid-sentence.  Yet, the text was perfectly understandable.  I knew what the author was saying.  And it gave the text a kind informality and colloquial feel to it; I felt a real connection to Malala herself on account of this narrative style.  When I went back to an English copy, it suddenly seemed so much more formal and straight laced.  As you said, these *pseudo-sentences* (my word, not yours) in Japanese created a kind of drama of their own that I felt was unfortunately lacking from the pages of the English text.

At any rate, as you can see, despite what I've written above I'm still kind of clinging to your idea of a "strictly speaking" proper sentence--that is, it needs a subject and predicate.

So, in summary, I would say that perhaps 文 and *sentence* aren't exactly equivalent terms.

Addendum:  as I think about this some more, it occurs to me that the difference may be one of orthography too.  Odd as it may sound, I thought of this when thinking of lines of Chinese poetry a written in groups of 4 or 5 characters.  Yet, they seem to form a unit.  Would they be called 文?  I haven't studied Chinese so I can't really say.  I have studied Sanskrit though, and in something like the Bhagavad Gita the defining unit is the meter of the shloka (verse).  At any rate, what I'm suggesting is that the visual (or aural, in the case of Sanskrit) presentation of the text itself is perhaps what originates the meaning of the word 文 or *sentence*.

Interestingly, my 漢和中辞典 gives one of the meanings of 文 as ことば。また、ことばが集まってまとまった意味を表わすもの。Additionally, the Japanese dictionary on my Mac would seem to define 文 as a unit of meaning.  So, I'd say again, this seems to suggest that the two (文 and sentence) are not quite equivalent.  文 seems to be defined semantically whereas sentence seems to be defined grammatically.  So there will be a substantial overlap between the two, but certainly not every complete semantical unit will necessary be a so-called complete grammatical structure warranting the name "sentence".

Comment: The definitions of *sentence* found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(linguistics)) and [on Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentence) look closer to what is written on 漢和中辞典. Perhaps there are two levels of "grammatically speaking" even among English speakers? One is what's written on Wikipedia by linguists and the other is what's taught at ordinary classrooms in the US. The former clearly permits the existence of [one-word sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_word). But I think I could grasp what people usually feel about the word.

Comment: @naruto Having taught in the US at both the K12 level (high school) and having taught as a university professor, there is a deplorable disconnect between the two.  In my experience, K12 teachers often define things in ways that need to be later unlearned by the students once they reach university.  As a minor example, in my own area of expertise, mathematics, I cannot tell you how many times I've run across high school math teachers who continue to teach  students that the number 1 is a prime number.  So, that there may be two levels of definition in the US is perhaps not surprising at all.

Comment: Okay, this answer perfectly explained why [my previous answer here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44295/5010) was so unpopular :D As an adult, it's far easier for me to read articles on Wikipedia than to know what is actually taught at school in the US. By the way, number 1 is never a 素数 at middle schools in Japan.

Comment: A sentence needing a verb is  utterly incorrect. I'm European, and I was never thought such a thing. Even in literal first grade, before we had such technical terms as "verb" or "predicate", they taught us that a "sentence is a standalone unit that expresses a thought". So things like "Hello!" or "What?" could easily fit that definition.

Comment: @Davor I'm not disagreeing with you at all.

Comment: An interesting parallel — as you note, the Japanese idea of 「文【ぶん】」 is defined semantically (as a unit of meaning), whereas "sentence" is defined grammatically or syntactically (based on the structure of the words used). I have found that the Japanese idea of 「自動詞【じどうし】・他動詞【たどうし】」 is defined semantically (based on the meaning of the verb, and whether an object of the action is inherently implied by the kind of action), whereas in English, the idea of "transitive / intransitive" is defined syntactically (based on whether or not an object is explicitly included in a given context).

Comment: So 「食【た】べる」 is _always_ a 他動詞【たどうし】, because the action of eating something inherently requires the existence of an object. Meanwhile, "eat" is either transitive or intransitive depending on context, specifically whether or not an object is explicitly included: "I eat" = intransitive (no object stated), "I eat it" = transitive (explicit object).

Comment: @Davor, looks like both definitions are current: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(linguistics) — so which one sounds "correct" to the individual is probably a matter of how the idea of "sentence" was taught in school. FWIW, I was taught the syntactically strict definition (US east-coast elementary schools in the early '80s), so "Hello!" would technically not be a "sentence" per se (no predicate / verb). But using the semantic definition, "Hello!" is a complete thought, and thus also a "sentence" from that point of view.

Answer (score 3):

Not having enough cred to just comment on A. Elliet's post, I'll add an answer.

First, relative to English, the sentence, "Hello!" can be read to have an implicit subject and verb, the object of which is the only word made explicit. Thus,

> I say to you, "Hello!"

(Recursive, yes?)

There are other ways of reading the implied sentence, of course. For example,

> Is anyone listening?

or

> I greet you.

Some people will disagree with the concept of substitution, but it is why we can make sense of otherwise incomplete utterances. Also, note that I do not say the words are there, I say we can read these partial expressions as if they were intended to be there and that way make sense out of them.

Japanese tends to rely much more on implicit completion than English.

Comment: +1 for "implicit completion". 