# Trouble parsing lyrics under lack of particles

Tags: syntax, poetry

As always, we have to take non-sentence poetry at face value; sometimes it is almost always ambiguous, but there is probably another perspective I am over looking. Taking a look at the final verse from きのこ帝国's second track from 渦になる, titled "退屈しのぎ" ([full lyrics and transcription / translation I'm working on](https://genius.com/12611903)):

```
唐突に始まるお前の昔話
聞きながらアルペジオ
冴えないノンフィクションの結末を
握っているお前の手は冷たいから嫌だ
やさぐれ吐く息に混じる声が歌い出す
```

The bits of this verse fall out pretty easily, but the way they fit together is a little hard for me. My attempt:

**唐突に始まるお前の昔話** == "Suddenly *it* begins, *your reminiscence*"

**聞きながらアルペジオ**  == Is the 昔話 being listen to, as in "while listening"? (Could it be ながら "although [in which case, does this imply an arpeggio is being "played"?]) Is this 聞き as in "ask"? Why is アルペジオ surrounded by no verb phrase or particles? Is it アルペジオを as in アルペジオをする?

**冴えないノンフィクションの結末を** == "concludes *the dark / sullen non-fiction*"

Could this 冴えない mean "boring / uninteresting" ? Does アルペジオがノンフィクションの結末する mean the same, as in, the arpeggio concludes the non-fiction?

**握っているお前の手は冷たいから嫌だ** == Does this 握っている describe お前, resulting in something like, "Your hand, that I'm clutching, is cold, so I hate (holding) it"

**やさぐれ吐く息に混じる声が歌い出す** == "Sings in a voice with a sulking breath"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as parsing goes, my brain is intuitively seeing three ["sentences"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48863/5010) in this verse.

- 唐突に始まるお前の昔話(を)聞きながら、アルペジオ。
- 【｛（冴えないノンフィクションの結末）を握っている→｝お前の手】は、冷たいから嫌だ。
- ｛（やさぐれ吐く息）に混じる声｝が、歌い出す。

Note:

- Some verb after アルペジオ is omitted. What's omitted is a very hard question for me. One easy option is to extract the アルペジオ part as a sentence word (like "Parsley sage rosemary and thyme.").
- 冴えないノンフィクションの結末 = the ending of a boring/uninteresting/mediocre non-fiction story
- ～を握っている = to have control/discretion over ～
- 握っているお前: 握っている modifies お前 (this is perfectly fine in Japanese), and お前 is the person who is doing the action of 握る.

Comment: So how about the 唐突に始まる that modifies お前, given the context (or if you want more you could check the OP for the rest of the lyrics), what meaning should I get from "you, who is suddenly beginning", or perhaps, "you, for whom something is suddenly beginning"? Is he beginning telling his/her story? Or is something else (implicit) beginning for him/her?

Comment: @KennedyRyan Ah, 唐突に始まる modifies お前の昔話 as a whole, not お前 alone. What suddenly started is the 昔話. If you're interested [see the discussion here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46817/5010).