# How can these two verbs affect 未来 at the same time?

Tags: grammar

> 私の進む先に輝く  希望あふれる未来

This sentence is separated like this in subtitles, with 私の進む先に輝く being above, and 希望あふれる未来 being below (somehow I think it might be relevant when it comes to my confusion in parsing it). At first I believed 輝く was modifying 希望.

I was told, however, it should be parsed like this: [私の進む先に輝く][希望あふれる]未来, as in both verbs are equally affecting the noun 未来. But what sort of structure is this in which 輝く can simply be in dictionary-form, before another noun, and still affect 未来 as a relative clause?

Answer (score 2):

More exactly the sentence should be parsed either as 1.(私の進む先に(輝く希望)あふれる)未来 or 2.((私の進む先に輝く)希望あふれる)未来.

In case 1, this is *the future filled with sparkling hopes that is waiting for you*; in case 2, this is *the future filled with hopes which are sparkling before you*.

Comment: In both cases, then, 輝く is acting on 希望 then, not on 未来, right? The person I asked specifically said the 未来 is both what was sparkling and what was filled with hope, which is why I was confused.

Comment: Yes, 輝く is modifying 希望. If the future is filled with *sparkling hopes* we could they that the future itself is sparkling but grammatically speaking 輝く modifies 希望 not 未来.

Comment: I parsed this like (私の進む先に輝く→)((希望あふれる→)未来) or something like "hope-filled future shining in front of me". That is, 輝く modifies (希望あふれる)未来.

Comment: @naruto I think that's the parsing I was told, and what my question is really about, for I don't really understand that structure. I guess it's a re-ordered 希望あふれる未来は私の進む先に輝く, but phrased in a more "literary" way?

Comment: @nath9 Yes, it's a 体言止め. [My previous answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61200/5010) may help.