# explanation of 俺だったが

Tags: word-choice, syntax, grammar

Hi I have found the following sentence

> "普段学校に行かず家に引き篭**もっている俺だったが**、今日は珍しく外出をした。"

translated as:

> Normally I stay locked in my room. Don’t even go to school. But today,
> for once, I left the house.

I wonder, why the 俺だったが was used ?
What would be the difference if the sentence were:

> 普段学校に行かず家に引き**篭もっていたが**、今日は珍しく外出をした。

Comment: Does this answer question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61196/5010

Comment: exactly, thanks for the reference