# Meaning of `願うは豊穣品足る礼賛`

Tags: grammar

There's this speech in the 2nd season of Kobayashi's Maid Dragon, I know it's just chuuni speak, but there's a part of it that I can't parse at all. Here's the full speech:

```
世を統べる影の王に奉らん
外法をもって これを最上とすべし
願うは豊穣(ほうじょう) 品足る礼賛
値を変え
さらなる碑(いしぶみ)をもたらせたまえ
我が魔は泥として広がり 穢(けが)れを
我が理(ことわり)は浸食し 狂気の氾濫(はんらん)を
正しき偽りへと書き換えを果たせ！
はあ～っ！
おいしくな～れ
萌え萌えキュ～ン！
```

This phrase: `願うは豊穣(ほうじょう) 品足る礼賛` doesn't even look like a sentence to me, so can anyone help me break it down, at least structure-wise?

EDIT:
Someone asked me to add my own interpretation so I will give it a go.

Looking at it again, could it be that the 足る is the same たる as in ~たる者 patterns? I looked through Tsubasa Web Corpus and I can actually find some examples of sentences like: `国民の代表足る者がこの品性の無さは正直、恥ずかしいですね。`

<s>So breaking it down, maybe it's something like this:</s>

<s>願うは豊穣品 足る 礼賛</s>
<s>A worship befitting for a wish of a gift of abundance</s>

Never mind `願うは豊穣品` is not nominalized, so that can't be it. So maybe:

願うは 豊穣品|足る|礼賛 (my wish is a praise of abundance gift)

Comment: I think you're gathering "close" votes out of concern that this is effectively asking for us to translate for you.  Could you show some of your own attempt at translating this?  Even just to list the meanings of the constituent terms?

Comment: I think it consists of two parts, 願うは豊穣 and 品足る礼賛.

Comment: I think it's just 願うのは, I see this zero-nominalization with verbs happen in ことわざ. Like http://kotowaza-allguide.com/ki/kikanuwaissyounohaji.html

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Added my interpretation

Comment: @OtheJared Not sure what you mean, what I'm confused about is the parts other than the `願うのは`
@aguijonazo What would `品足る礼賛` mean in this context?

Comment: 品足る礼賛 would mean 品が足りる礼賛. I have no idea what this is supposed to mean in this spell. I have no context. I’m impressed you understood the other lines.

Comment: @aguijonazo I guess maybe it's something like 'worship of sufficient quality`? It's less that I "understand" what the rest mean and more that I at least know what they're saying (it's just chuuni speak that doesn't have much to do with the story, so I don't context would help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably two "sentences":

- 願うは豊穣。
  It's fertility that I with for.
  <sub>(The archaic version of 願うのは豊穣(だ))</sub>
- 品足る礼賛。
  Adoration for things/goods/merchandise being abundant!
  <sub>(So-called [呼体句/体言止め](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/86022/5010); semantically something like 品が足ることを礼賛しよう)</sub>

The word after 品 is unlikely to be the auxiliary たる because 品である礼賛 makes even less sense to me (but you may want to refer to the original comic). Note that the auxiliary たる has nothing to do with 足る, so that 代表足る者 is a plain typo. If the kanji 足 is used, it surely is a verb meaning "to be sufficient/enough".

Comment: @aguijonazo 「しな」です。2期第1話なのでAbemaでもアマプラでも無料で配信されています。[これ](https://gxyt4.app.goo.gl/xZQ1F)の6分あたりです。例のオムライスの話だと分かっていてもなお、ぶっちゃけ後半何が言いたいのかよく分かってないです。中二心が足りない…。