# Is there an easy way to translate/understand 体言止め sentences?

Tags: grammar, translation, sentence

I am having trouble understanding 体言止め sentences in the book that I am reading.

I understand *some* 体言止め sentences, like the one in [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36793/large-qualifiers-before-nouns-or-unusual-sentence-orders/36801#36801):

> 来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている伊藤。

My way of understanding this is just to move the 体言 at the end to the start and add a が.

> 伊藤が来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている。

And then the sentence makes a lot of sense and can be easily translated to English.

However, I failed to understand this 体言止め from 幼女戦記第1巻:

> 建前に従わなければ「悪い子」になってしまうという恐怖感。

And here's the context:

> 小学生のころ、誰もが義務教育によって人間とは生まれながらにして平等であると習うだろう。その時、一人一人が平等でかけがえのない大切な存在だと教わるのだ。だが、建前とは裏腹に不平等というのは簡単に見つけられる。
>
> どうして、前の席の子は自分よりも身長が高いのだろうか？どうして、クラスにはドッジボールのうまい子と下手な子がいるのだろうか？どうして、隣の席の子はあんな簡単な問題も解けないのだろうか？後ろの席の子は静かに先生の話を聞いていられないのだろうか？
>
> だが、小学生は「良い子」であるべきだという環境下にあった。皆違うけれども、皆大切な存在だと言われているのだ。建前に従わなければ「悪い子」になってしまうという恐怖感。
>
> だから、「良い子」達は「悪い子」とならないように努力した。

Literally translated, it's "The fear that if they don't follow the rules they will be regarded as 'bad children'."

As you can see, in English, that's just a noun phrase and I don't understand what it means.

I tried to move 恐怖感 to the front and add a が, but I still struggles to translate it in to a normal English sentence.

> 恐怖感が建前に従わなければ「悪い子」になってしまうという。
>
> The fear いう that if they don't follow the rules they will be regarded as "bad children".

I don't know what I should translate いう to. And even if it is translated I think the whole thing sounds kind of weird.

How can I translate 体言止め easily? What I mean is, just like the fact that you can replace "X + は" with "As for X" and it always makes an understandable English sentence, is there something similar for 体言止め?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

日本語が分かるとして回答します。

体言止めを理解するためには、体言止めの持っている「勢い」を感じとる感性、あるいはこれから生じるであろう現象を想像する豊かな想像力が必要です。

体言止めを感じていただくために、体言止めとはどのようなものであるかを２つ例を挙げてみます。

- 道路を一台の車が走っています。とろこが、あるところで突然道がなくなり、車は空中に放り出されます。でも、その車はまだどこかにぶつかって壊れてはいません。
- 水面が静かな池に石を投げ込みます。投げた石は池の表面に届きました。これからどうなるでしょう。 なお、松尾｛まつお｝芭蕉｛ばしょう｝の有名｛ゆうめい｝な俳句｛はいく｝「古池｛ふるいけ｝や　蛙｛かわず｝飛｛と｝び込｛こ｝む　水｛みず｝の音｛おと｝」はこの類｛たぐい｝です。

質問者の例題に戻ります。

（Ａ）「来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている伊藤。」
と
（Ｂ）「伊藤が来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている。」
とではその意味するところは静的には同じです。

（Ｂ）は必要な説明はすべて終わっておりますので、それ以上の物語の進展はありません。
一方（Ａ）は「伊藤」の体言止めで文章は終わっておりますので、読み手の能力に応じていくらでも物語が進展できます。もちろん、読み手の推察する物語の進展部分はそれまでの文脈から判断して書き手の想定したものであることが普通ですが、読み手の想像力が書き手のそれより優れている場合には、全く違う展開を生む可能性があります。

私は、（Ａ）からは、平凡に「来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている伊藤、**これから期待される若手有望株です。**」のような文脈を想像します。

（Ｂ）では表現できない文章の発展が、文字数が（Ｂ）とほぼ同じ（Ａ）の体言止めによって実現されております。この追加されて推定される部分が体言止めの持っている「勢い」です。

---

## EDIT

（A）と（B）とを使って、体言止めの文と普通の文とどこが違うのかの本筋を説明します。

普通の文である（B）は、主語が「伊藤」で述語が「抜擢されている」です。
しかし、（A）の体言止めでは、主語が「伊藤」でその前の「来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている」は、「伊藤」を修飾している形容句であり、「来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている伊藤」全体で１つの名詞句です。（A）には、長い名詞句である主語がありますが、この文には述語がありません。従って、読み手は、「伊藤」を修飾している形容句から、記述されていない述語を想像する必要があります。
従って、（A）と（B）とでは本質的に異なります。すなわち、（B）は完結した文、（A）は読み手による述語の補完を期待する未完成の文、但し補完に必要な情報が形容句に十分書かれた未完の文です。

---

## EDIT 2

> 建前に従わなければ「悪い子」になってしまうという恐怖感。

この体言止めの文に続く私が想像で補完するフレーズは次のようなものです。

- こればかりは、避けたい。
- これが、いつも私にはついてまとった。

これらのフレーズを追加することで、はじめてこの文に続く「だから、「良い子」達は「悪い子」とならないように努力した。」という文が自然に続くようになります。どうですか。

---

## EDIT 3

体言止めについてはここでも[回答](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48811/is-this-sentence-gramatically-correct-ano-ko-ga-futteita-makka-na-sukaafu/48885#48885)しました。

OPが「Is there an easy way to translate/understand 体言止め sentences?」と書いていますが、たぶん to understand は、できると思います。
しかし、 to translate into English は、かなり難しいと思います。

難しい理由を説明します。[ここ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48811/is-this-sentence-gramatically-correct-ano-ko-ga-futteita-makka-na-sukaafu/48885#48885)には、体言止めは that を使った relative clause で表現できることが書かれています。

> To add to psosuna's answer, it's worth noting that the line in question is not a sentence, grammatically speaking. It is a noun phrase, with スカーフ as the main or "head" noun and the preceding portions all describing the scarf. English makes use of relative clauses, with "that" used to coordinate, whereas Japanese allows modifying phrases to directly modify nouns.

確かに、論理的には、名詞句(noun clause) としてrelative clauseで表現できますが、日本語の体言止めと、英語のrelative clauseを使ったnoun clauseとでは、核となる名詞(the main or "head" noun)の文章における位置が大変異なり、これが英訳を困難にします。

> 日本語：あの子が振っていた**真っ赤なスカーフ**
>   　　　　ano ko ga futte ita *makka na sukāfu**
>
> 英語：**the pure-red scarf** that that girl was waving

前にも説明しましたように体言止めでは、文として省略された部分を読者が補完する必要があります。名詞で終わっている不完全な文を完全にするための「核となる名詞」が体言止めの文では文の最後にあり、しかもこれから補完するフレーズの重要な名詞として先頭の位置にありますので、補完作業が物理的にも、気持ちの推移の観点からでも大変スムーズにできます。一方英語では、「核となる名詞（the main or "head" noun）」が不完全である文の先頭にあるので、これから補完すべきフレーズと大変遠い位置にあることになります。従って、日本語の体言止めの文がもっている「勢い」を補完時に上手につなげていくことが日本語の場合より難しくなります。

私は、英語は日本語にくらべて上手でないので正解は述べられませんが、日本語の体言止めを英語に翻訳するには、relative clauseを使ったnoun clauseに続いて、読者に補完して欲しいフレーズの最初の少しの部分を次のように付け加えて置くという方法があるのでないかと思っています。

- the pure-red scarf that that girl was waving **which I** ...
- the pure-red scarf that that girl was waving **because she** ...

体言止めの日本語を上手に英訳する方法を考えてください。また、うまくいきましたら発表してください。

Comment: つまり、想像力を使わなければ体言止めを理解できなくて、翻訳もできないですか。

Comment: @Sweeper: その通りです。しかし、「来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている伊藤、**これから期待される若手有望株です。**」の想像して追加したフレーズは、「～伊藤。」までの文章を見たり聞いたりした人は誰でも若干の文言の違いはあっても想像できる内容です。

Answer (score 3):

> 来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている伊藤。
>   My way of understanding this is just to move the 体言 at the end to the start and add a が.
>   伊藤が来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている。

You're right. In this case, the whole line is a noun phrase, with a relative clause (来年公開の映画『獣道』でも主演に抜擢されている) modifying a noun (伊藤).

As for your second example:

> 建前に従わなければ「悪い子」になってしまうという恐怖感。

This time, the noun at the end is not the subject for the preceding part. The という here is appositive (同格). In other words, 建前に従わなければ「悪い子」になってしまう is a description/content of the 恐怖感.

Considering the context, I think you can read it this way, supplementing the omitted/implied (verb) phrase at the end of the sentence:

> 建前に従わなければ「悪い子」になってしまうという恐怖感**があった**。

So in a case like this you'd need to guess from the context what verb/verb phrase is being left out or implied.

Comment: So what you mean is that sometimes a verb can be left out, and we need to infer the verb from the context, then translate it? Can there be anything else that is left out?

Comment: @Sweeper はい、どんな動詞句がその文脈に当てはまるか、想像して判断するしかないと思います。普通は、動詞句が省かれていると思います。