# Understanding ~並みに and ending a sentence with a noun

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, syntax

The sentence in question is:
カズマの発言にいきり立つ、ゴブリン並みに短気な二人。

I get first part of getting angry at Kazuma's statement but the second part has 2 things I don't quite get:

1.並み after the word goblin, the word has so many meanings on Jisho but I'm not sure which, if any of them actually fit here.

2.The sentence ends in 二人, which is a noun. Based on what I've learned, shouldn't the last part of a sentence always be a verb?

Comment: The essence of "カズマの発言にいきり立つ、ゴブリン並みに短気な二人。" is "短気な二人。".　Only by "短気な二人。" it does not make sense in particular. If you show me some sentences before and after the sentence in question, I could consider why 体言｛たいげん｝止｛ど｝め is used here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

１． ～[並]{な}み, when attached to a noun as a suffix, means "the same level as ~~" "to the same degree as ~~" "equal to ~~".  ゴブリン並みに短気 means "as short-tempered as goblins" "short-tempered just like goblins".

２．It ends with a noun because it's a noun phrase containing relative clauses.

> ［カズマの発言にいきり立つ、］［ゴブリン並みに短気な］二人。
>   *Lit*: "The two, who are as short-tempered as goblins and get furious at Kazuma's statement."

This is a kind of rhetorical technique called "[体言]{たいげん}[止]{ど}め". For more on this topic, you can refer to this thread: [What exactly is 体言止め？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14529/9831)

Comment: I've always wondered what these noun phrase sentences are called. 答えを得た、幸せなsiikamiikaさん。

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware of noun phrases, just recently started learning the language. This helps a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. 並み means 'level' or 'like' in this case. 'ゴブリン並みに短気な二人' means 'Those two are short tempered just like goblins.' or 'Those two are goblin-level short tempered.'
2. No, japanese sentences do not always end with verbs. Sometimes, verbs are omitted, and other times the positions of subjects and objects are switched. In this case, it seems to be the latter. If I rewrite this into a subject-verb sentence, 'ゴブリン並みに短気な二人はカズマの発言にいきり立つ。

Answer (score 0):

> カズマの発言にいきり立つ、ゴブリン並みに短気な二人。

If you want a verb at the end of the sentece, you could say as

> カズマの発言にいきり立つ、ゴブリン並みに短気な二人**であった**。

The above expression is often used by writers in their novels.