# Saw this sentence in the title of an article and I'm a bit confused

Tags: grammar, translation, usage, particles

日本のスノーアクティビティを体験
If the particle を is used here shouldn't it be 体験した/する if it is acting like a verb?

Comment: Your question is answered here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/1628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common headline style. In both English and Japanese, headlines are written in a clipped, abbreviated style. For example:

> Queen to address parliament

Is a perfectly normal and comprehensible headline but would be unacceptable in speech or narrative prose. Omission of the する in する verbs, especially at the end of a headline, is common in Japanese. Here's a paper on the subject:

[Transforming a Sentence End into News Headline Style](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/I05-5006)

It's not really relevant in this case because 体験 sounds fine in casual speech, but another characteristic of Japanese headlines is strong reliance on 漢語, probably both for formality and to save space.

Comment: Ah thanks I got it, but in casual speech it'd still be 〜を体験する right

Comment: Yes, certainly!