# Sentences consisting of only a long attribute and a noun

Tags: grammar, meaning

Take this one from [天狗 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A9%E7%8B%97)  as an example:

> 飛鳥時代の日本書紀に流星として登場した天狗だったが…

1. Is it the same as

   天狗は飛鳥時代の日本書紀に流星として登場したが…
2. Why do you use `だった` instead of `だ` here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you understand how a Japanese [体言止め](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/5010) sentence works, I think this is a 体言止め-like expression, too. It's semantically the same, but looks more dramatic or emphatic.

Comment: ^ What naruto said. This is a kind of literary/stylistic device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is (A) 飛鳥時代の日本書紀に流星として登場した天狗だったが the same as
>      (B) 天狗は飛鳥時代の日本書紀に流星として登場したが?

Although (A) and (B) are logically same, Tengu is emphasized more in (A) than in (B), and as a nuance, I feel, they are quite different.

(A) 飛鳥時代の日本書紀に流星として登場した天狗だったが…
*It was Tengu that appeared as a meteor in Nihon-shoki (the oldest chronicles of Japan) in the Asuka period, but now it is just a legendary creature with an unnaturally long nose.*

(B) 天狗は飛鳥時代の日本書紀に流星として登場したが…
*Tengu appeared as a meteor in Nihon-shoki (the oldest chronicles of Japan) in the Asuka period, but now it is just a legendary creature with an unnaturally long nose.*

> 2. Why do you use だった instead of だ here?

Since the time when the Tengu was thought to be a meteor is a past or the Aska period, it is expressed in the past tense.