# Trying to understand this tweet

Tags: translation, words, internet-slang

Not sure why, but although I'm not bad at understanding japanese, sometimes there are messages like this I cannot understand at all. Could someone help me understand how the overall grammar works here ?

> 1| ドラゴンボールワールドツアー当日予選大会
>
> 2| 4枠中、2枠しか出れない+シングルイリミのルール
>
> 3| 行く人はツイッターで牽制してて既に戦いが始まってる感
>
> 4|ルール的には最後に行うであろう4がいいはずやけど、
>
> 5|それで4に強い人が集まりすぎると逆に美味しく無いし、どこ登録するかの読み合いが難しい

I guess I kind of understand the first sentence, which seems to give context (It's about the day of the Dragon Ball World Tour preliminary tournament)

No idea for 2|, although I understand the *"single elimination rule"* part. I don't understand what 枠 means in this context. It doesn't make sense to me.

3| Not sure about that one either, maybe the 感 at the end bears the meaning of *"I have the feeling that..."* but again, the overall sentence doesn't make sense to me. *"I have the feeling that the persons who will go will do XXX on twitter, and the fight will have already started"*. Sounds horrible to me! :p

4|I still don't know what 枠 means here, except that there are 4 of these.

5| *''And then, when the ones who are strong against '4' will gather.....(something)''* Sounds more like the start of a legend to me than a translation coming from a tweet... :p

**OK**, so I literally did not understand anything from this tweet. I'm not sure if it's about the vocabulary, or the grammar, or both. But this tweet totally throws me off. How would you translate it?

Comment: I think 枠 is like a slot in the tournament.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mainly about the understanding of the rule of the event...

- This 枠 ("slot", or in this context "bracket") refers to [these 4 independent LCQ (last chance qualifier) tournaments](https://smash.gg/tournament/red-bull-final-summoning) that will be held before the day of the grand final. As of the writing of this tweet, each player was able to enter only two of them, but looks like this [restriction was waived later](https://twitter.com/PhongDacBiet/status/1075167013792755712).
- Yes 感 is a suffix meaning "feeling of ～", and this is technically a long [体言止め](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/5010) sentence. "I have the feeling that" is the correct interpretation. 牽制 ("keeping in check") refers to all the "metagaming" happening on Twitter, something like "I'll enter LCQ #2 and #3 (so others may want to avoid these)", "I think I'm gonna use this character (although I may be lying)". This tweet itself may be a 牽制 because it's somehow trying to discourage people from applying to LCQ #4.
- 4に強い人が集まり過ぎる is not "too many players who are strong against 4 gather" but "too many strong players gather to LCQ #4".

---

Here's my translation (the original Japanese is using more casual and loose grammar)

1. Dragon Ball World Tour LCQs (literally "same-day preliminary tournaments").
2. One cannot enter more than 2 brackets out of 4 + Single elimination rule.
3. Contestants are playing mind games on Twitter. It kinda feels like the battle has already started.
4. According to the rule, LCQ #4 (presumably the last one) should be the most advantageous, but...
5. If too many strong players gather to #4, that's not good. The mind reading of which LCQ to register with is difficult.

I don't know why this person is thinking #4 is the most advantageous, but there may be some explanation on the official rule book.

Comment: From all the information I learned so far, 4| then seems to mean: "Since according to the rules the 4th bracket should start last it should be good but.." and he then explains how gathering all the top players in this one bracket is not a good idea. And 2| would mean: "Out of the 4 brackets, we can only go into two of them"?  and 3| would be something like: "I have the feeling that the fight has already started since I must keep an eye on Twitter..." Anyway, would it be possible to add your own translations of this tweet to your answer?

Comment: @Ushiromiya Added my translation.