# Why can't I say してますよって感を出す?

Tags: grammar, usage, suffixes, construction

It seems 感 in 感を出す often directly follows a noun:

> 絵に立体感を出そうと苦心した ([source](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E7%AB%8B%E4%BD%93%E6%84%9F/))

> マット感を出したい/ウエット感を出したい ([source](https://adept-hair.net/category/item/itemgenre/finish-feeling/mat/))

> 新商品のプロモは高級感を出そう ([source](https://english.cheerup.jp/article/4208))

A lot of 漢語 + 感 patterned words seem already lexicalized and are understandably so used. カタカナ語 + 感 follows the same pattern and thus makes sense too. But what about these sentences:

> 上司はそれに気づいているのか気づいていないのかわかりませんが、距離を縮めようとしたり私のためにしてあげてますよ感を出してきます。 ([source](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11259689526))

> なのにそれなのに政府はアメリカをはじめ世界の国に日本もウクライナ助けてますよ感を出したいのか．．．

The part preceding 感 appears to be or close to being a quote. Considering って感じ/という感じ are very common constructs, why can't I say

> 距離を縮めようとしたり私のためにしてあげてますよって感を出してきます

> 距離を縮めようとしたり私のためにしてあげてますよという感を出してきます

Comment: "距離を縮めようとしたり私のためにしてあげてますよ感を出してきます" is grammatically noncompliant . "なのにそれなのに政府はアメリカをはじめ世界の国に" just sounds immature.

Comment: @dungarian I also realized なのにそれなのに政府はアメリカをはじめ世界の国に was not the most elegantly written sentence, but immature in what regard? The expressed idea?

Comment: Not the expressed idea, but rather the choice of words. "なのにそれなのに" sound off in this context. Maybe it's just me though, as it's a subjective point.

Answer (score 5):

You can't say the last two sentences because 感【かん】 is not an independent word but a suffix meaning *-ness*. You cannot use *ness* as an independent word in English, either. For the last two sentences to work, you need to use (～という/って)感じ instead.

私のためにしてあげてますよ感 is a highly informal expression meaning something like *I'm-doing-this-for-you-kinda atmosphere* (correct this if it's strange). This 感 is attached to a clause, but it's still a suffix. It should be avoided in formal sentences, but something like this is catchy and interesting on Twitter, etc. Another example [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64462/5010).

Comment: There is a non-suffix use of 感 as a (semi-)independent noun that is synonymous with 感じ. (A corresponding definition on デジタル大辞泉: ２ 物事に接して生ずる心の動き。感じ。「今さらの感は否めない」「隔世の感」)  In this use, 感 can take clausal and other types of modifiers just like other nouns (whether or not mediated by the content-indicating という).  E.g.「全体の構成にぎくしゃくした感が残る」「なんだこれは、っていう感が強い前半」「使い勝手が中途半端な制度であるという感を否めない」「肩に独り立ちさせた親父って感が漂ってました」

The two versions in the question sound not at all problematic to me, though I understand that 感じ would be a more common choice there.

Comment: @goldbrick ！　確かに単独の名詞としても普通に使われますね、言われて気付きました。大事なことですし是非回答として書いていただけると。