# How is the adverb さっそく acting in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

別に今日だって約束してたわけじゃないし

さっそく感が恥ずかしすぎる

In the second part, it seems like she's saying it like.. "the feeling of impatience is too embarrassing?" I'm too embarrassed of my impatience?"

Edit: From context she wants to see her crush as the talked before and said they'd see each other again after her work was done. Now she wants to go see him, but technically speaking they didn't promise to see each other a particular day.

Comment: Where are you getting the meaning "impatience" from?

Comment: Provide more context.

Comment: Wasn't it either さっそくな感じ or さっそく感 by any chance?

Comment: さっそく感 yes. Added some context

Answer (score 1):

さっそく is an adverb/no-adjective that basically means "without delay" or "promptly" when used positively:

- さっそく始めましょう。
  Without further ado, let's begin!

But in a negative context, it can have a connotation of "hastily", "too soon" or "skipping the usual preliminaries":

- さっそくで申し訳ありませんが…
  I apologize for the rush, but...
- え、さっそく?
  Huh, so soon? / Oh, already?
- 彼は初日にさっそく失敗した。
  He made a mistake all too soon on the first day.

This 感 is a suffix. Traditionally, it follows a fixed set of difficult kango (e.g., 罪悪感 "sense of guilt", 多幸感 "euphoria"), but informally, it can follow various words or clauses to say *X-kinda feeling*, *X-ish vibe* or *X-ness*.

- [Why can't I say してますよって感を出す?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94436/5010)
- [Trying to understand this tweet](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64462/5010)

When combined, さっそく感 forms an informal noun phrase that refers to a sense of hastiness or being rushed. さっそく感が恥ずかしすぎる means that someone's statements or actions are so hasty or eager that they become embarrassing.

Comment: I'm curious -- you say, _"[感] is usually used with kango"_. I thought さっそく **is** a kango word? References list this with the spelling 早速, which would fit the reading as _on'yomi_.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Ah yes 早速 is a kango! I fixed my explanation.