# 配信 sentence construction problem

Tags: grammar

> Nouvelle-Calédonieで繰り広げるロードトリップはウェブ動画でも配信

In this sentence, why did we end the sentence at 配信? What does this mean?

Comment: Related: [What exactly is 体言止め?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/9831)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use the definition No.2 below. And probably the program is broadcasted on TV and you can watch it also on the website of TV station since it is a little bit unusual to imagine that individuals to broadcast their road-trip at "[Nouvelle-Calédonie](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Nouvelle-Cal%C3%A9donie&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)" due to the cost.

"配信" does not imply live-streaming and you need to say "生配信" or "生中継{なまちゅうけい}" for live-streaming at least in my use.

According to [コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%85%8D%E4%BF%A1-598864)

1. 通信社・新聞社・放送局などが、入手した情報やニュースを支社や他のマスコミ機関・官庁・企業などに配送すること。通信社が新聞社・放送局に、新聞社の本社から支社へ、放送局の親局から地域局へ、記事・番組などを送ること。
2. インターネットを利用して、企業や個人が動画や音楽、情報などを送信すること。