# What is the meaning of 出るべきところ here?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

> 首から下に目を向ければ、すらりと伸びきった四肢や、引き締まっていながらも胸や腰など**出るべきところ**はきちんと出ているメリハリの利いたグラマラスボディ。

What does 出るべきところ mean here ?

Also what does `メリハリの利いたグラマラスボディ`modify here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- 出るべきところ (literally "the parts that should protrude") is a common Japanese euphemism for (usually female) breasts and hips. It's a paraphrase of 胸や腰など. 出る(べき)ところが出ている (literally "where the parts that should protrude are protruding") is almost a set phrase to describe a glamorous female person.
- メリハリの利いたグラマラスボディ modifies nothing, because it's just a predicate of a [体言止め](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/5010) sentence. The simplified version of the sentence is:

  > 四肢やグラマラスボディ。
  >   *(I can see)* (Her) arms/legs and glamorous body!

  引き締まっていながらも胸や腰など出るべきところはきちんと出ているメリハリの利いた is a long relative clause that modifies グラマラスボディ.