# Help with translation

Tags: translation

Hi I came across this sentence in a light novel:
地元から一番近いショッピングモールまで出て、本屋で買い物して昼飯を食べてくるぐらいの余裕は持てる懐具合。
I need help with translating this and I do not understand the purpose of the noun at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what exactly is "体言止{たいげんど}め"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/what-exactly-is-%e4%bd%93%e8%a8%80%e6%ad%a2%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e3%81%92%e3%82%93%e3%81%a9%e3%82%81)

Comment: 体言止め is a Japanese grammar which use a noun at the end of the sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation will be like this?

> I can afford to go out to the nearest shopping mall from my hometown, to shop at a bookstore and to have a lunch.

About The purpose of the noun, 懐具合, it's a technique that can draw attention to the text that follows. It is called as 体言止め in Japanese.

Comment: "I'm afford" is not correct English.

Comment: Changed: I'm afford → I can afford