# Sentence ending in 娘

Tags: meaning

It's difficult for me to understand why both lines end in 娘. Is this some sort of quirk? It's from a character bio in Tokimeki Memorial 2. The general meaning of the sentence is clear, but the ending is confusing me.

「運動大好き、スポ一ツ娘

勉強もよくできる娘」

Comment: Are these sentences from character descriptions?

Comment: Yes, it's a report from another schoolmate ingame.

Comment: Are you familiar with the attributive form?

Answer (score 5):

Simply, だ or です is omitted after 娘. Technically, this is called [体言止め](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/5010). だ/です is usually omitted in titles, captions, headlines, tables, and so on. (Even in English, obvious phrases like "this is a" are left out in captions, etc.)

スポ一ツ娘【むすめ】 is a set phrase meaning "sporty girl". 勉強もよくできる娘【こ】 is a noun phrase with a relative clause, "a girl who is also good at studies". (Note that 娘 in a context like this usually just means "girl" rather than "daughter", and is read こ as a standalone noun.)