# Is it common to end the sentence with 事?

Tags: grammar

Is  it common to end the sentence with  事　?
(not the imperative case)

I have often encountered sentences such as

> 我が望みは、爆裂魔法を放つ事。
> My only desire is to let off Explosion.

I understand that 事 is the 事 of nominalization and it could be followed by だ　or です。

What nuances does the absence bring (if any) when compared to

> 我が望みは、爆裂魔法を放つ事だ。

or

> 我が望みは、爆裂魔法を放つ事です。

Due to the usage of 我が, I would be inclined to think it gives more formality, but I am not really sure.

Comment: For context: this was spoken by [Megumin](https://konosuba.fandom.com/wiki/Megumin) who is known as chuunibyou from *KonoSuba*.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/5010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance it makes it sound more dramatic and possibly pompous.

If the sentence is stand alone (as opposed to being part of a longer text), then it's just briefer and doesn't have this effect.  E.g. if you had a list with a sentence `今年の目標はもっと野菜を食べること`, then it's not dramatic or pompous - it's just briefer than writing `今年の目標はもっと野菜を食べることだ`.

If you write

> 今年の目標はもっと野菜を食べること。その方が環境負荷が低いのである。

Then it's a writing technique that delivers slightly more impact than writing `今年の目標はもっと野菜を食べることだ。` If you do it a lot it could create a pompous impression (or at least poor style).

It's useful to vary the rhythm. For example, `今年の目標はもっと野菜を食べること。その方が環境負荷が低いのだ。` would be considered a better style than `今年の目標はもっと野菜を食べることだ。その方が環境負荷が低いのだ。` as you avoid repeating だ.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explaination ! Indeed the character that pronounced this sentence likes to make dramatic introductions and use elaborate expressions.