# 俺だけ入れる隠しダンジョン and its grammatical issue

Tags: grammar, particle-だけ

> **俺だけ入れる隠しダンジョン。**
> The Hidden Dungeon Only I Can Enter.

The above sentence is a title from winter 2021 anime. Is the sentence grammatically correct? Why does not it written as:

> **俺だけが隠しダンジョンを入れる。**

or

> **俺だけは隠しダンジョンを入れる。**

These sentences I suggested is according to rules of the particle だけ . It's confusing me.

Answer (score 4):

> [俺]{おれ}だけ[入]{はい}れる[隠]{かく}しダンジョン。

Grammatically speaking, this is not a full sentence, but a noun phrase with a relative clause. 俺だけ入れる is a relative clause that modifies 隠しダンジョン.

> 〔俺だけ(が*)入れる〕隠しダンジョン。
> = The Hidden Dungeon 〔(that) Only I Can Enter〕.

*が is left out here.

This structure is often used for a title of a story, novel, anime, etc. It uses a rhetorical device called 体言止め. For more, see: [what exactly is "体言止{たいげんど}め"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/9831)

Its non-relative version would be:

> 俺だけ(が)隠しダンジョンに*入れる。 or 隠しダンジョンに俺だけ(が)入れる.
> = Only I can enter the hidden dungeon.

*The verb [入]{はい}る takes the particle に to mark the indirect object. It doesn't take the direct object (～を). [入]{はい}れる is the potential form of [入]{はい}る, as you may know.