# Using に to make a comparison

Tags: particle-に

I came across the following sentence in an old Japanese text a while ago and am wondering about the use of に here:

> 工場の規模極めて小さく且使用機械不完全なる為め、製品の品質本邦產品に劣り。

Now I am pretty sure that the に here is used to make a comparison. But I have never seen に used like this. So is this use of に to make a comparison common?

Comment: Common I don't know but when you compare two things you are confronting one **in** the other. You can also think of it as に対して劣り (inferior against the other)

Comment: Umm.... **what** sentence?

Comment: Thank you @[Oran Matheus](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/54992/) for (re?) entering the relevant Japanese sample sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather that 劣{おと}る (and its opposite 勝{まさ}る/優{まさ}る) takes に-phrases. They correspond literally *inferior/superior **to***. So に is used for comparison as commonly as *to* is used for comparison.

---

I assume 劣り is a typo for 劣る.

Comment: Thanks! And no 劣り is not a typo. Might just have to do with this being an early 20th century text.

Comment: @Polsci54, you can upvote the answer and mark it as resolved if it solved your question.

Comment: @Polsci54 I see, then it should be a [体言止め](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14529/45489).

Comment: @sundowner It's just present tense of 劣る verb without any formal ending (e.g. ます). Not a typo, especially if the text is talking about technical things.

Comment: @vdegenne, the 連用形 of a verb has no tense.