「彼の名前はジョン・レノン。」 Why leave out でした?
From the Genki II textbook, 3rd Edition page 303, there is a story building up to how John Lennon met Yoko Ono at one of her art exhibits.  The writer introduces a long-haired man coming in and looking at one of Yoko's art pieces, before finally revealing 「彼の名前はジョン・レノン。」
Since this passage uses proper/polite writing, you'd grammatically expect a でした (or possibly です) at the end.  What are the specifics on when this omission is OK in proper writing (I know in casual speech omitting だ/だった is more flexible); and what nuance does it convey?

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/9831

It's difficult to convey the nuance of 体言止め in a single phrase, but generally, when used effectively in novels and essays, it has the effect of making the sentence dramatic.
